# python RPyC user count

Tags: python, rpyc

I wish to use RPyC to provide an API for a hardware board as a service. 
The board can only cater for a single user at a time. 
Is there any way I can get RPyC to enforce that only a single user can get access at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would work (or work well), but you can try starting a [OneShotServer](https://rpyc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/utils_server.html#rpyc.utils.server.OneShotServer) inside a loop, thus at any given moment only one connection is served. When the connection is closed, the server terminates, and you start another one for the next client.

Something like:

```
is_aborting = False
while not is_aborting:
    server = OneShotServer(myservice, *args, **kwargs)
    # serve the next client:
    server.start()
    # done serving the client
```

If this doesn't work, your best bet is to subclass [ThreadedServer](https://rpyc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/utils_server.html#rpyc.utils.server.ThreadedServer), and override the [_accept_method](https://rpyc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/rpyc/utils/server.html#ThreadedServer) method to keep track if there's already a connection open, and return an error if there is.

Comment: Thanks, I am not quite ready to implement this but it is coming shortly. I'll test it out but the solution looks very promising indeed.